# Proper way to initiate object on map

Tags: c++, dictionary, object, insert, stdmap

I have a std::map that has a int as key and an object pointer as value. On creation, should I first instantiate objects separately and then insert them at the container, or can I simply call the "new" tag right at the insert method? Is there any advantage of using one of those other than simplifying code?

```
map<int, Foo*> sample;

Foo* foo = new Foo();

sample.insert(pair<int, Foo*>(0, foo));       //case 1
sample.insert(pair<int, Foo*>(0, new Foo())); //case 2
```

Comment: Both are correct. Depends whether you want to you `foo` later on. As a side note, you might as well use `.emplace`.

Comment: or also sample[0] = new Foo(), which is semantically different but in this case equivalent.

Comment: Case 2 allows move construction, but you are using pointers and pointers don't move more efficiently than they copy on any realistic architecture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should single-use values be inline, function-level const variables, or class-level static const variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026019/should-single-use-values-be-inline-function-level-const-variables-or-class-lev)

Comment: Thanks, guys. It clarified that they are both accepted, though applied on different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the object ownership policy used in your program.

If you expect the ownership of the dynamically allocated object to lie with `sample`, then either of the methods is ok. You'll have to make sure that before `sample` goes out of scope, all the dynamically allocated objects contained in it are deleted.

If you expect the ownership of the dynamically allocated object to not lie with `sample`, then the second method will cause a memory leak while the first method allows you to delete the object after you are done using it.

You can use smart pointers to manage life time of dynamically allocated objects. Then your code will become simpler no matter which method you use to add objects to the map. E.g.

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> sample;
sample.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::make_unique<Foo>()));
```

Comment: One of my doubts with this question was exactly this "who has the control over the object", which can be dangerous if we lose control of things. Thanks for the answer! It clarified a lot.

Comment: @JosneiLuisOlszewskiJunior, you're welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: I would suggest using std::unique_ptr instead of the raw pointer.  It will a better job maintaining the lifetime of the object.  In you sample, you may be leaking the new'ed pointers. Instead of new, use make_unique<Foo>.